# При переходе по ссылке на php файл он скачивается, а не переходит на другую страницу сайта

Tags: php, html, ссылки

При переходе по ссылке на php файл он скачивается, а не переходит на другую страницу сайта. Есть такой код:

```
<nav id="logo">
    <a href="./index.php"></a>
</nav>
```

Здесь index.php - это главная страница файла. Когда нажимаю на эту ссылку (на сайте), у меня скачивается файл index.php , хотя по идее должен переходить на главную страницу сайта. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю и как это исправить?

Comment: необходимо настроить сервер, скорее всего пхп интерпретатора нет

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, где надо настроить сервер и как? (хостинг лежит на reg,ru)

Comment: @KirillPeace где - зависит от nginx || apache.  Как - никто не будет вам этого говорить т.к довольно обширная тема. Ищите ответы в гугле по поводу конфигов сервера, либо у фрилансеров. Сначала проверьте, стоит ли у вас интерпретатор..если нет - apt-get в помощь (ubuntu).

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего первое, но всякое бывает:

1.Возможно у вас не установлен сам РНР. Или запрещено его использовать (если хост какой то).
2. Попробуйте выставить права на РНР файл или настроить индекс файлы на сервере

Comment: Файл php установлен точно, причем начальную страничку назвал index.php . Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выставить права?

Comment: Тут [https://losst.ru/prava-dostupa-k-fajlam-v-linux](https://losst.ru/prava-dostupa-k-fajlam-v-linux) все расписано

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте так

```
<nav id="logo">
    <a href="./"></a>
</nav>
```

но вообще, у вас что-то с хостингом, возможно просто отключен интерпретатор php.